# Padding n rows and m columns of 0s to the each side of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

So here's the  problem

> Given a 2D numpy array 'a' of sizes  n×m . You need to pad the matrix
> with 0s so that the dimensions of the matrix become  (n+2n1)×(m+2m1)

```
a = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]])
n1 = 1
m1 = 2
print(padding(a, n1, m1))
>>[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I thought solving it with the pad() function, but here is the problem with it

```
import numpy as np

def padding(a, n1, m1):
    return np.pad(a, [n1, m1], constant_values=0)
a = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]])
n1 = 1
m1 = 2
print(padding(a, n1, m1))
```

Result is

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 0 0]
  [0 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Read the `np.pad` docs a bit more carefully.  You can specify 4 pad values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
result = np.pad(a, [(n1, n1), (m1, m1)])
```

The second parameter (*pad_width*) is a list of 2-tuples (*before*, *after*)
for each axis.

Padding with zeroes is the default mode, so you don't need to specify it.

The result is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

A more concise version is:

```
np.pad(a, [(n1,), (m1,)])
```